# How to submit multiple array checkbox value from database to another page

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I am trying to submit multiple arrays with a checkboxs which is the value of checkboxs is from my database but I am not able to get the value, here is what I have so far

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$sql = '
  SELECT DISTINCT v_co_dept_sn
  FROM v_co_comp_info
  ORDER BY v_co_dept_sn ASC
';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table style="border: 0px">
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td>';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="jabatan[]" value="' . $row['id'] . '"/>';
    echo '</td>';
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking. What is the desired output and what is the output you are currently getting?

Comment: What happens when you run it? Do you get any PHP errors? (ie something about `$row['id']`)

Comment: So, where's the rest of the form?

Comment: *"I am trying to **submit** multiple arrays"*, um, how, with the mystical submit button next to the Tarot cards? What am I missing here?